# Released Windows Phone App showing blank screen, but not in Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm building an app using Phonegap for the Windows Store. I am able to successfully run the app to a connected device from Visual Studio Express. It runs perfect. I have also ran the app by using the Application Deployment Tool to deploy the XAP file. This also runs perfect.

After everything was going good I submitted the app to the Windows Phone Store. It was denied. The exact reason was "The application launches to a blank screen.". I then realized that I could release this app as a beta app to myself. I did this and I got the same result. The application launches to a blank screen. Any ideas on what is going on when I'm submitting my app to the Windows Phone Store.

Update: I'm sorry I forgot to add that I have used Weinre to debug the app also. From doing this I can verify that its not even getting to the actual web app portion of the code. Therefore I know its not a js error causing this issue.

Another Update: The app I am currently trying to get to work has a very simple index.html file. In the app the index.html is like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location = 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com';
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

The redirect seems to be what is causing the issue. I have taken that out and put a static html page in there and it works fine. I have also read about the isScriptEnabled property in Windows Phone apps. Do I need to set this to true? If so where is it located?

Comment: Maybe there is a javascript error that prevents the app from loading

Comment: See above update....sorry I forgot to mention that initially

Comment: A similar case happen with android was a ajax call I was making during app startup I had to move them to a later stage so the app doesn't crash. Are you sure the assets are being copied and the cordova.js or phonegap.js is referenced.

Comment: These are being referenced properly as far as I can tell. If these issues were causing the problem, wouldn't I see them when I deployed to device during testing? The problem only occurs after I submit the application.

Comment: The last idea is try to decompile or open the XAP so you can see it's contents. Maybe the DEBUG target is doing someting that the RELEASE is not.

Comment: I did do that, but most of the suggestions say to make sure the correct DLLs are referenced. To be honest I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for. Also, just another note, in VS Express I am able to select Release in the solutions configuration and deploy to the device and it works fine. Also, the XAP file I used in the Application Deployment tool is the Release XAP file. So I'm not finding any difference between the Debug and Release versions, only between the Release and the Store versions.

Comment: I found a tool for WP similar to LOGCAT in Android that can show you the application logs. It very useful because the console.log writes there. [How to get debug log from Windows Phone 8](https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/14289/how-to-get-debug-log-from-windows-phone-8.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting the following capability in the WMAppManifest.xml file

```
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
```

Answer (score 0):

@jb1785

are you sure? If this capability is not enabled, you could n't have run it on your machine too.

Comment: That's the confusing part to me. To make it 100% clear though, I was never able to run the application on the emulator. I am running Windows 8.1 in a VM (virtual box) so I don't have the ability to run the emulator. I have strictly been using a Lumia 520 for my testing.